# Registering car cosigned by another person who lives in another state

Tags: vehicle, illinois, michigan

I am currently renting and working in the state of Illinois.  However, I was thinking about buying a car and having my dad who lives in Michigan cosign for it.  I still consider my "permanent address" to my parents place in Michigan. Is it legal for me to register my car in Michigan?  Would the answer change if I could make my dad a co-owner on the car?

Comment: Related to : [link](http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/13338/how-long-can-a-vehicle-registered-and-owned-by-a-person-in-one-state-be-used-in/13339#13339)

Answer (score 1):

The question of where you are a resident is supposed to be a matter of objective fact rather than subjective viewpoint, but the law (in Illinois) does not give a uniform legal definition of residency. For instance if you have an out of state driver's license, you are not a resident, for tuition purposes. If you are in Illinois "for other than a temporary or transitory purpose during the taxable year", you are a resident [for tax purposes](ftp://www.ilga.gov/JCAR/AdminCode/086/086001000J30200R.html), which includes being "employed in a position that may last permanently or indefinitely". If you are registered to vote in Illinois, you are a resident. The matter of residency has presumably been established in connection with employment and state income tax. As a resident, you are required to transfer your vehicle registration to Illinois [(625 ILCS 5/3-101(a))](http://www.ilga.gov/legislation/ilcs/ilcs4.asp?DocName=062500050HCh%2E%203&ActID=1815&ChapterID=49&SeqStart=35500000&SeqEnd=67900000)

> Except as provided in Section 3-102, every owner of a vehicle which is
>   in this State and for which no certificate of title has been issued by
>   the Secretary of State shall make application to the Secretary of
>   State for a certificate of title of the vehicle.

However, if the vehicle is owned by a non-resident because of 3-102 which says that

> No certificate of title need be obtained for...(3) a vehicle owned by
>   a non-resident of this State and not required by law to be registered
>   in this State

If you co-own the car, this raises the question whether the fact that it is also owned by a non-resident means that the vehicle need not be registered in Illinois (as long as it is registered in Michigan: see the reciprocity section (625 ILCS 5/3-402(B))). The statute does not directly address the matter of co-ownership where the owners are residence of different states, but under a literal reading of §102 the fact of it being registered to a Michigan co-owner should suffice to be in compliance with the law. Naturally, your (Illinois) attorney should inform you as to what the law is.